# What is the difference between OpenTSDB and Graphite?

Tags: monitoring, metrics, graphite, opentsdb

As far as I can tell, here are the main differences:

1. [OpenTSDB](http://opentsdb.net/) does not deteriorate data over time, unlike [Graphite](http://graphite.wikidot.com/) where the size of the database is pre-determined.
2. OpenTSDB can store metrics per second, as opposed to Graphite which has minute intervals (I'm not sure of this, Graphite docs show retention policies which stores metrics every minute, but I don't know if this is the minimum unit of time we can play with)

I want to make an informed decision about which tool to use in order to store metrics, have I missed any other differences in these 2 systems? How performant/scalable are they?

Bonus Question: Is there any other time series system I should look at?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Disclaimer: I wrote [OpenTSDB](http://opentsdb.net).

I would say that the biggest advantage of **Graphite** seems to be **superior graphing capabilities**.  It offers more graph types and features.  **Deployment complexity** is also probably a bit lower with Graphite, as it's not a distributed system and thus has fewer moving parts.

**OpenTSDB**, on the other hand, is capable of storing a significantly larger amount of fine-grained data points.  This comes at the cost of deploying **HBase**, which isn't that big of a deal to be honest.  If you want to get **real-time data down to the second** with >>10k new data points/s, then OpenTSDB will suit you well.

Some info about our *current* scale at StumbleUpon (these numbers generally double every 2-3 months):

- Over 1B new data points per day (=12k/s on average).
- Hundreds of billions of data points stored.
- Less than 2TB of disk space consumed (before 3x replication by HDFS).
- Read queries are generally capable of retrieving, munging and plotting over 500k data points per second.

Comment: Graphite's interval is configurable.  I typically use 10-second monitoring periods.  And the graphs are really sweet.  Otherwise, I think tsuna's answer is bang-on

Answer (score 20):

**User interface**

**Graphite** has some superb graphing tools available. The default web interface is ugly (although functional), but you then have a wealth of great graphing and dashboard options.

A few examples:

- [Grafana](http://grafana.org) dashboard, with dynamic (zoomable) graphs

[image: grafana dashboard example]

- [Vimeo's GraphExplorer](https://github.com/vimeo/graph-explorer) dashboard

[image: graph explorer dashboard example]

- [Cubism.js](http://square.github.io/cubism/) horizon charts

[image: cubism.js chart example]

Look [here](http://dashboarddude.com/blog/2013/01/23/dashboards-for-graphite/) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15840928/318557) to find many more.

**OpenTSDB** on the other is still at the gnuplot stage:
[image: OpenTSDB web interface]

**Setup**

In practice, Graphite is actually much more of a pain to setup than HBase + OpenTSDB. OpenTSDB has a comprehensive documentation and a few straightforward steps. [These are the commands to install Graphite](https://gist.github.com/jgeurts/3112065), things get even trickier if you build from source.

**Performances**

> OpenTSDB does not deteriorate data over time, unlike Graphite where the size of the database is pre-determined.

True. Also Graphite uses a file format similar to RRD, in practice this means a single data point will take as much disk space as the full time serie since this space is pre-allocated. This also means plotting an empty time interval will take as much time as if there was data there (an alternative storage engine, [Ceres](https://github.com/graphite-project/ceres), is in the work but I haven't tried it yet).

As tsuna said OpenTSDB will let you store significantly more data points, leveraging the power of Hadoop's HDFS. Graphite on the other hand, whose architecture is [detailed in this AOSA chapter](http://www.aosabook.org/en/graphite.html), is a more adhoc solution.

> OpenTSDB can store metrics per second, as opposed to graphite which has minute intervals.

Nope, both can log down to the second.

Comment: it looks like opentsdb is great for storing data and graphite is best for graphing. Is it possible to point graphite to opentsdb for backend. I would be curious to see if anybody was able to connect to opentsdb from graphite.

Comment: Note that Grafana also supports OpenTSDB, and there are other attractive frontends for OpenTSDB such as [metrilyx](https://github.com/Ticketmaster/metrilyx-2.0).

Comment: @WilfredHughes makes a good point about Grafana supporting OpenTSDB. Also note that OpenTSDB can store down to millisecond precision.